# Is there any way of checking progress of Cypher query execution?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I execute queries that go through the whole, quite big graph. At the moment some of them take 10m and others go up to 3h and even more. However, it is just a start. I already have to break some of them after a few hours because I do not know if they will end in ten minutes or 10 years. It would be very helpful to see some kind of progress during the execution.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment such a feature does not (yet) exist. There is a plan to provide a way to kill a running query conveniently in one the upcoming releases.

In the meantime you can go with a feature that is not part of the public API called guards. Mark did a nice writeup at http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/17/neo4j-setting-query-timeout/

Comment: My intention is not to kill long queries. I could wait for the result a lot of time, but it has to be reasonable amount for example not longer than day or even week. Moreover, I do not want to wait one week and see timeout. If I could see some indicator of progress, I would know that waiting is not pointless.

Comment: In this case the answer is simply "no". Maybe a future version might have this.