# The way to check progress of Cypher query execution (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Are there any function to know the progress of the query execution or estimate the time to return the query result ?

Almost the same question were asked three years ago.
([Is there any way of checking progress of Cypher query execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802756/is-there-any-way-of-checking-progress-of-cypher-query-execution/52107629#52107629))

At that time ,there was no such function.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no way to see the progress of query.

Neo4j comes with the procedure `CALL dbms.listQueries()` where you can see some informations about your queries (execution time, cpu, locks, ...) but not the progress of your query (you can also type `:queries` in the neo4j browser).

Generally what I do to see the progress of a write query with periodic commit (ex: a LOAD CSV), is to write a read query that counts the number of updated/created node.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Following is the sample query I execute.

MATCH p=(a:word_data1)-[r:rel_data1*1..3]-(b:word_data1)  Where a.name = "xxx" RETURN p  LIMIT 100　.

When I see the execution plan with EXPLAIN command , it has 8 STEPs before return the result .

①NodeByLabelScan
②Filter
[....]
⑦ProduceResults
⑧Result .

Can I know which STEP of the process is being executed in real time?

Comment: It's the same question ... if you know the step, then you have the progression of the query. So like I said it's not possible. Sorry